# How can I find out which thread crashed inside my program?

Tags: c++, windows

Consider the following program:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

std::atomic<int> crashId;

void threadFunction(int id) {
    while (id != crashId) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
    int* p = nullptr;
    *p = id;
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(&threadFunction, 1);
    std::thread t2(&threadFunction, 1);
    int id;
    std::cin >> id;
    crashId = id;
    while (true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}
```

I start the program (built in Release mode) and go to lunch. When I come back a colleague has typed in either 1 or 2.

How can I find out which thread crashed? Alternatively how could I rewrite the program so that I could find out this the next day?

I tried the Event Viewer. That only seemed to report the process id and filepath to my .exe.

If I had each thread running in a separate .dll would I see this in the Event Viewer log?

Comment: Note that while you deliberately invoke undefined behaviour by assigning to a dereferenced null pointer, that in itself doesn't guarantee a crash.

Comment: @G.M. - that's just being pedantic.

Comment: @selbie Not necessarily. At least Clang tends to [warn on deliberate null pointer writes](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/P7zj784od), and refuses to crash there. It doesn't warn on OP's code though, and I didn't check what it compiles it to.

Comment: @selbie Ok, it's possibly a bt pedantic but I think it's worth stressing that undefined behaviour really is undefined: i.e. don't *expect* a particular outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, you can set a registry key associated with your program's name to generate a dump file when a crash happens

Sample instructions [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/kb/how-to-generate-crash-dump-on-windows-machine.html) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps?redirectedfrom=MSDN)  (I always recommend generating "full" crash dumps)

With the crash dump in hand, you can load it into a tool such as Windbg or even Visual Studio to observe the call stack and see variable values.

You'll likely need to have the PDB files associated with the EXE in your tool's symbol path to see the function and variable names.  Optimized builds are often harder to debug, but there are some compiler switches that generate better (and larger) PDB files that make retail debugging almost as good as non-optimzed builds.

Comment: Is there a runtime cost associated with this feature or is all the work being done when the crash occurs?

Comment: There is no runtime cost.